# Expected behavior of tf.maximum

Tags: tensorflow

I am seeing an un expected behavior when using tf.maximum, here is my code snippet and output:

anchor, positive, negative = y_pred[0], y_pred[1], y_pred[2]

```
# Step 1: Compute the (encoding) distance between the anchor and the positive, you will need to sum over axis=-1

pos_dist = tf.square(tf.abs(tf.subtract(anchor,positive)))

# Step 2: Compute the (encoding) distance between the anchor and the negative, you will need to sum over axis=-1

neg_dist = tf.square(tf.abs(tf.subtract(anchor,negative)))

# Step 3: subtract the two previous distances and add alpha.

basic_loss = tf.subtract(pos_dist,neg_dist) + alpha

# Step 4: Take the maximum of basic_loss and 0.0. Sum over the training examples.

#printing the first  5 elements to debug

print(basic_loss[0,0:5].eval())
print(tf.maximum(basic_loss[0,0:5].eval(),0).eval())
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.maximum(basic_loss,0.0))
```

[ 19.11461067 -31.52009964 -25.84571075  10.3833456    6.87008572]
[ 15.39834023  19.75396919   0.          16.64770508   0.11121483]

Any/all guidance or ideas are greatly appreciated

Comment: Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Need to see more of your code to help. Looks like output of basic_loss can vary each time you evaluate.

Comment: I added more of the code per your suggestion, and basic_loss should not change each time it gets evaluated in this context.   Thanks

Comment: Do you get the expected result if you execute `print(sess.run([basic_loss[0,0:5], tf.maximum(basic_loss[0,0:5], 0)]))`?

Comment: Yes, your code does get me the expected results, thx. I don't understand why ruling eval() on basic_loss would give different results each time, if the tensor is already set and not changing.